# Issue sorting CSV input data by date using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to sort a collection of CSV files within a directory using PowerShell and then want to export the results to a new single CSV file.

My code executed without error but the the results are not sorted correctly.

My Source data looks like this (this is a sample for testing):

```
"TimeCreated","TargetUserSID","UserName","Domain","Message","Remark"
"04.12.2017 13:56:56","S-1-5-21-66666666-777777777-888888888-99999","User123","testlab.internal","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"04.12.2017 13:56:48",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Workstation unlocked"
"04.12.2017 13:56:48",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Workstation unlocked"
"04.12.2017 13:56:34",,"User123","testlab.internal","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
"04.12.2017 10:29:49",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:29:49",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:27:27","S-1-5-21-66666666-777777777-888888888-99999","User123","testlab.internal","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"08.11.2017 09:24:58",,"","","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
"08.11.2017 09:23:14",,"","","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
"04.12.2017 10:25:35",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:25:35",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:23:20","S-1-5-21-66666666-777777777-888888888-99999","User123","testlab.internal","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"04.12.2017 10:23:14","S-1-5-21-2025377670-2384379295-2560266631-1005","Admin","TestClientWin7","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"04.12.2017 10:22:44",,"Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:22:44",,"Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:22:38",,"Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:22:38",,"Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:20:28",,"Admin","TestClientWin7","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
"01.12.2017 11:39:17",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"01.12.2017 11:39:17",,"User123","testlab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
```

My result looks like this:

```
"TimeCreated","TargetUserSID","UserName","Domain","Message","Remark"
"01.12.2017 11:39:17","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"01.12.2017 11:39:17","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:20:28","","Admin","TestClientWin7","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
"04.12.2017 10:22:38","","Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:22:38","","Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:22:44","","Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:22:44","","Admin","TestClientWin7","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:23:14","S-1-5-21-66666666-777777777-888888888-99999","Admin","TestClientWin7","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"04.12.2017 10:23:20","S-1-5-21-964984727-670836246-1844936127-10903","User123","tetslab.internal","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"04.12.2017 10:25:35","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:25:35","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:27:27","S-1-5-21-964984727-670836246-1844936127-10903","User123","tetslab.internal","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"04.12.2017 10:29:49","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 10:29:49","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)"
"04.12.2017 13:56:34","","User123","tetslab.internal","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
"04.12.2017 13:56:48","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Workstation unlocked"
"04.12.2017 13:56:48","","User123","tetslab.internal","Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet","Workstation unlocked"
"04.12.2017 13:56:56","S-1-5-21-964984727-670836246-1844936127-10903","User123","tetslab.internal","Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung","User initiated Logoff."
"08.11.2017 09:23:14","","","","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
"08.11.2017 09:24:58","","","","Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos","Failed Login !"
```

This is my code:

```
$SortingCSV = @()
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\*.csv" | ForEach-Object{
    $SortingCSV += Import-Csv $_
}
$SortingCSV | Sort-Object TimeCreated | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 "c:\temp\sorted.csv"
```

Comment: It looks like its sorting alphabetically, you need to convert timecreated to a datetime object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fields imported from the CSV are strings, so they're sorted in string order, not date order, so the sorting is absolutely correct, just not what you were expecting. You need to calculate a proper `DateTime` value for `Sort-Object` to work with to get the rows sorted in date order. I would also recommend not appending to an array in a loop.

```
$pattern = 'dd\.MM\.yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName } |
    Sort-Object { [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.TimeCreated, $pattern, $culture) } |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\sorted.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoType -Force
```

Comment: thank you for your contributions. excellent solution and description.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs because the TimeCreated column is being sorted alphabetically due to be being interpreted as a string value. One way to handle this would be to convert it to a DateTime object. You can do this within the `Select-Object` cmdlet by using a calculated property:

```
$SortingCSV | Select -ExcludeProperty TimeCreated @{N='TimeCreated';E={Get-Date $_.TimeCreated}},* | Sort-Object TimeCreated | Export-CSV ..
```

The above excludes the TimeCreated property byt then recreates it with the same name by using `Get-Date` to return a date object for the string value it contains.

Comment: This would work too, but has the disadvantage that the format of the `TimeCreated` column might get changed inadvertently (if the regional settings specify a different date/time format than what is present in the input data).

Comment: Yes be wary of regional variations with dates that will occur depending on where the script is run. Ansgar's answer is better in that regard as it makes the expected date pattern explicit.